# How to fetch a value from a cell and use it as a prefix for a term in another cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 sheets in a spreadsheet, 1 which is the list of all the words / definitions, like this:

---

[image]

---

And another that is a bunch of *derived* words, like this:

---

[image]

---

In the derived word sheet, I would like for it to place in the C column the "custom" word, plus the word "trut". Like `{custom} trut`. It pulls `custom` by using column B in the derivative sheet as a key to lookup the row in the main sheet. Then from the main sheet, it pulls the corresponding `custom` column value.

How can this be done? I know how to implement basic formulas, but not sure how to accomplish the templating, and how to use the input as a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this formula in Cell C2 of the "derived words" sheet. It will automatically populate any matched words, and will display "not found" (you can change this) if a match can't be found.

`=iferror(arrayformula(vlookup(B2:B8,{definitions!D2:D,definitions!C2:C},2,false)&" trut"),"not found")`

---

- The "range" for `VLOOKUP` is expressed as an array. This enables the formula to return a value to the left of the search column).

  - Reference:  [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en).
  - Normally the "range" in `VLOOKUP` is one or more adjacent/contiguous columns; the left-most column contains the search key and the "index" references the column number containing the value to return - this is a column to the *right* of the lookup column. **BUT**, in this question, we need to lookup a value in Column D and then return the value in Column C (*to the left*).
  - To do this, we create our own array by using brackets `{ }`. The array consists of two columns: C & D **but we reverse the order** =>: `{definitions!D2:D,definitions!C2:C}.
  - `VLOOKUP` searches the first column (Column D) for the "search key" and returns the value from Column C.
- `&" trut"` is the method to add "trut" to the value returned by `VLOOKUP`.
- `arrayformula` - used to apply the formula to all the derived values in column C.
- `IFERROR` - a troubleshooting method to avoid an error.

Comment: Works like a charm, can you explain more what is happening with the vlookup method? Also, how do I show it blank (or not found) without "trut" if col D is present but col C is not?

Comment: Try this: `=iferror(arrayformula(vlookup(B2:B8,{definitions!D2:D,definitions!C2:C},2,false)),"not found")`. On a tangent, the derived words can be easily compiled from the definitions using a formula. For example, a `QUERY`.